# Having trouble with my React JS Tutorial

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass, gulp

I'm following React JS Tutorial for Beginners - Build a website using React, Sass, Gulp and Node.js
I'm getting Failed to Complied with the follow message

```
./src/App.js 
  Module not found: Can't resolve './Assets/css/default.min.css' in '/Users/qiangbarejie/Desktop/react/reactTutorial/my-react-project/src'
```

*This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.*

My App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Assets/css/default.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header>
           Test header
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 export default App;
```

my gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

// dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

///////////////
// - SCSS/CSS
///////////////

var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';

// Compile SCSS_SRC
gulp.task('compile_scss', function(){
  gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(minifyCSS())
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min '}))
  .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
});

// detect changes in SCSS
gulp.task('watch_scss', function(){
  gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, ['compile_scss']);
});

// Run tasks
gulp.task('default', ['watch_scss']);
```

If someone knows how I should solve this problem, please help me out I would greatly appreciate, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the file `default.min.css` in folder `/Users/qiangbarejie/Desktop/react/reactTutorial/my-react-project/src/Assets/css/`?

Comment: Yes, I have the file "default.min.css" in folder. When I run gulp from the terminal, it render mini css codes in the "default.min.css" file.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I double checked the path carefully and found out I made a careless typo. I put an extra space in my default.min.css file name. Now it's working again!!! Thanks.